# NullPointer Exception in readStringValues method in WinRegistry class

Tags: java

Here is the `WinRegistry` class I am using to readStringValues for a Key and am getting `NullPointerException`:

```
public class WinRegistry {
  public static final int HKEY_CURRENT_USER = 0x80000001;
  public static final int HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = 0x80000002;
  public static final int REG_SUCCESS = 0;
  public static final int REG_NOTFOUND = 2;
  public static final int REG_ACCESSDENIED = 5;

  private static final int KEY_ALL_ACCESS = 0xf003f;
  private static final int KEY_READ = 0x20019;
  private static Preferences userRoot = Preferences.userRoot();
  private static Preferences systemRoot = Preferences.systemRoot();
  private static Class<? extends Preferences> userClass = userRoot.getClass();
  private static Method regOpenKey = null;
  private static Method regCloseKey = null;
  private static Method regQueryValueEx = null;
  private static Method regEnumValue = null;
  private static Method regQueryInfoKey = null;
  private static Method regEnumKeyEx = null;
  private static Method regCreateKeyEx = null;
  private static Method regSetValueEx = null;
  private static Method regDeleteKey = null;
  private static Method regDeleteValue = null;

  static {
    try {
      regOpenKey = userClass.getDeclaredMethod("WindowsRegOpenKey",
          new Class[] { int.class, byte[].class, int.class });
      regOpenKey.setAccessible(true);
      regCloseKey = userClass.getDeclaredMethod("WindowsRegCloseKey",
          new Class[] { int.class });
      regCloseKey.setAccessible(true);
      regQueryValueEx = userClass.getDeclaredMethod("WindowsRegQueryValueEx",
          new Class[] { int.class, byte[].class });
      regQueryValueEx.setAccessible(true);
      regEnumValue = userClass.getDeclaredMethod("WindowsRegEnumValue",
          new Class[] { int.class, int.class, int.class });
      regEnumValue.setAccessible(true);
      regQueryInfoKey = userClass.getDeclaredMethod("WindowsRegQueryInfoKey1",
          new Class[] { int.class });
      regQueryInfoKey.setAccessible(true);
      regEnumKeyEx = userClass.getDeclaredMethod(  
          "WindowsRegEnumKeyEx", new Class[] { int.class, int.class,  
              int.class });  
      regEnumKeyEx.setAccessible(true);
      regCreateKeyEx = userClass.getDeclaredMethod(  
          "WindowsRegCreateKeyEx", new Class[] { int.class,  
              byte[].class });  
      regCreateKeyEx.setAccessible(true);  
      regSetValueEx = userClass.getDeclaredMethod(  
          "WindowsRegSetValueEx", new Class[] { int.class,  
              byte[].class, byte[].class });  
      regSetValueEx.setAccessible(true); 
      regDeleteValue = userClass.getDeclaredMethod(  
          "WindowsRegDeleteValue", new Class[] { int.class,  
              byte[].class });  
      regDeleteValue.setAccessible(true); 
      regDeleteKey = userClass.getDeclaredMethod(  
          "WindowsRegDeleteKey", new Class[] { int.class,  
              byte[].class });  
      regDeleteKey.setAccessible(true); 
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  private WinRegistry() {  }

  /**
   * Read a value from key and value name
   * @param hkey   HKEY_CURRENT_USER/HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
   * @param key
   * @param valueName
   * @return the value
   * @throws IllegalArgumentException
   * @throws IllegalAccessException
   * @throws InvocationTargetException
   */
  public static String readString(int hkey, String key, String valueName) 
    throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException,
    InvocationTargetException 
  {
    if (hkey == HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE) {
      return readString(systemRoot, hkey, key, valueName);
    }
    else if (hkey == HKEY_CURRENT_USER) {
      return readString(userRoot, hkey, key, valueName);
    }
    else {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("hkey=" + hkey);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Read value(s) and value name(s) form given key 
   * @param hkey  HKEY_CURRENT_USER/HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
   * @param key
   * @return the value name(s) plus the value(s)
   * @throws IllegalArgumentException
   * @throws IllegalAccessException
   * @throws InvocationTargetException
   */
  public static Map<String, String> readStringValues(int hkey, String key) 
    throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException,
    InvocationTargetException 
  {
    if (hkey == HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE) {
      return readStringValues(systemRoot, hkey, key);
    }
    else if (hkey == HKEY_CURRENT_USER) {
      return readStringValues(userRoot, hkey, key);
    }
    else {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("hkey=" + hkey);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Read the value name(s) from a given key
   * @param hkey  HKEY_CURRENT_USER/HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
   * @param key
   * @return the value name(s)
   * @throws IllegalArgumentException
   * @throws IllegalAccessException
   * @throws InvocationTargetException
   */
  public static List<String> readStringSubKeys(int hkey, String key) 
    throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException,
    InvocationTargetException 
  {
    if (hkey == HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE) {
      return readStringSubKeys(systemRoot, hkey, key);
    }
    else if (hkey == HKEY_CURRENT_USER) {
      return readStringSubKeys(userRoot, hkey, key);
    }
    else {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("hkey=" + hkey);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Create a key
   * @param hkey  HKEY_CURRENT_USER/HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
   * @param key
   * @throws IllegalArgumentException
   * @throws IllegalAccessException
   * @throws InvocationTargetException
   */
  public static void createKey(int hkey, String key) 
    throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException,
    InvocationTargetException 
  {
    int [] ret;
    if (hkey == HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE) {
      ret = createKey(systemRoot, hkey, key);
      regCloseKey.invoke(systemRoot, new Object[] { new Integer(ret[0]) });
    }
    else if (hkey == HKEY_CURRENT_USER) {
      ret = createKey(userRoot, hkey, key);
      regCloseKey.invoke(userRoot, new Object[] { new Integer(ret[0]) });
    }
    else {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("hkey=" + hkey);
    }
    if (ret[1] != REG_SUCCESS) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("rc=" + ret[1] + "  key=" + key);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Write a value in a given key/value name
   * @param hkey
   * @param key
   * @param valueName
   * @param value
   * @throws IllegalArgumentException
   * @throws IllegalAccessException
   * @throws InvocationTargetException
   */
  public static void writeStringValue
    (int hkey, String key, String valueName, String value) 
    throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException,
    InvocationTargetException 
  {
    if (hkey == HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE) {
      writeStringValue(systemRoot, hkey, key, valueName, value);
    }
    else if (hkey == HKEY_CURRENT_USER) {
      writeStringValue(userRoot, hkey, key, valueName, value);
    }
    else {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("hkey=" + hkey);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Delete a given key
   * @param hkey
   * @param key
   * @throws IllegalArgumentException
   * @throws IllegalAccessException
   * @throws InvocationTargetException
   */
  public static void deleteKey(int hkey, String key) 
    throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException,
    InvocationTargetException 
  {
    int rc = -1;
    if (hkey == HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE) {
      rc = deleteKey(systemRoot, hkey, key);
    }
    else if (hkey == HKEY_CURRENT_USER) {
      rc = deleteKey(userRoot, hkey, key);
    }
    if (rc != REG_SUCCESS) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("rc=" + rc + "  key=" + key);
    }
  }

  /**
   * delete a value from a given key/value name
   * @param hkey
   * @param key
   * @param value
   * @throws IllegalArgumentException
   * @throws IllegalAccessException
   * @throws InvocationTargetException
   */
  public static void deleteValue(int hkey, String key, String value) 
    throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException,
    InvocationTargetException 
  {
    int rc = -1;
    if (hkey == HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE) {
      rc = deleteValue(systemRoot, hkey, key, value);
    }
    else if (hkey == HKEY_CURRENT_USER) {
      rc = deleteValue(userRoot, hkey, key, value);
    }
    if (rc != REG_SUCCESS) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("rc=" + rc + "  key=" + key + "  value=" + value);
    }
  }

  // =====================

  private static int deleteValue
    (Preferences root, int hkey, String key, String value)
    throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException,
    InvocationTargetException 
  {
    int[] handles = (int[]) regOpenKey.invoke(root, new Object[] {
        new Integer(hkey), toCstr(key), new Integer(KEY_ALL_ACCESS) });
    if (handles[1] != REG_SUCCESS) {
      return handles[1];  // can be REG_NOTFOUND, REG_ACCESSDENIED
    }
    int rc =((Integer) regDeleteValue.invoke(root,  
        new Object[] { 
          new Integer(handles[0]), toCstr(value) 
          })).intValue();
    regCloseKey.invoke(root, new Object[] { new Integer(handles[0]) });
    return rc;
  }

  private static int deleteKey(Preferences root, int hkey, String key) 
    throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException,
    InvocationTargetException 
  {
    int rc =((Integer) regDeleteKey.invoke(root,  
        new Object[] { new Integer(hkey), toCstr(key) })).intValue();
    return rc;  // can REG_NOTFOUND, REG_ACCESSDENIED, REG_SUCCESS
  }

  private static String readString(Preferences root, int hkey, String key, String value)
    throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException,
    InvocationTargetException 
  {
    int[] handles = (int[]) regOpenKey.invoke(root, new Object[] {
        new Integer(hkey), toCstr(key), new Integer(KEY_READ) });
    if (handles[1] != REG_SUCCESS) {
      return null; 
    }
    byte[] valb = (byte[]) regQueryValueEx.invoke(root, new Object[] {
        new Integer(handles[0]), toCstr(value) });
    regCloseKey.invoke(root, new Object[] { new Integer(handles[0]) });
    return (valb != null ? new String(valb).trim() : null);
  }

  private static Map<String,String> readStringValues
    (Preferences root, int hkey, String key)
    throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException,
    InvocationTargetException 
  {
    HashMap<String, String> results = new HashMap<String,String>();
    int[] handles = (int[]) regOpenKey.invoke(root, new Object[] {
        new Integer(hkey), toCstr(key), new Integer(KEY_READ) });
    if (handles[1] != REG_SUCCESS) {
      return null;
    }
    int[] info = (int[]) regQueryInfoKey.invoke(root,
        new Object[] { new Integer(handles[0]) });

    int count = info[0]; // count  
    int maxlen = info[3]; // value length max
    for(int index=0; index<count; index++)  {
      byte[] name = (byte[]) regEnumValue.invoke(root, new Object[] {
          new Integer
            (handles[0]), new Integer(index), new Integer(maxlen + 1)});
      String value = readString(hkey, key, new String(name));
      results.put(new String(name).trim(), value);
    }
    regCloseKey.invoke(root, new Object[] { new Integer(handles[0]) });
    return results;
  }

  private static List<String> readStringSubKeys
    (Preferences root, int hkey, String key)
    throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException,
    InvocationTargetException 
  {
    List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
    int[] handles = (int[]) regOpenKey.invoke(root, new Object[] {
        new Integer(hkey), toCstr(key), new Integer(KEY_READ) 
        });
    if (handles[1] != REG_SUCCESS) {
      return null;
    }
    int[] info = (int[]) regQueryInfoKey.invoke(root,
        new Object[] { new Integer(handles[0]) });

    int count  = info[0]; // Fix: info[2] was being used here with wrong results. Suggested by davenpcj, confirmed by Petrucio
    int maxlen = info[3]; // value length max
    for(int index=0; index<count; index++)  {
      byte[] name = (byte[]) regEnumKeyEx.invoke(root, new Object[] {
          new Integer
            (handles[0]), new Integer(index), new Integer(maxlen + 1)
          });
      results.add(new String(name).trim());
    }
    regCloseKey.invoke(root, new Object[] { new Integer(handles[0]) });
    return results;
  }

  private static int [] createKey(Preferences root, int hkey, String key)
    throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException,
    InvocationTargetException 
  {
    return  (int[]) regCreateKeyEx.invoke(root,
        new Object[] { new Integer(hkey), toCstr(key) });
  }

  private static void writeStringValue 
    (Preferences root, int hkey, String key, String valueName, String value) 
    throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException,
    InvocationTargetException 
  {
    int[] handles = (int[]) regOpenKey.invoke(root, new Object[] {
        new Integer(hkey), toCstr(key), new Integer(KEY_ALL_ACCESS) });

    regSetValueEx.invoke(root,  
        new Object[] { 
          new Integer(handles[0]), toCstr(valueName), toCstr(value) 
          }); 
    regCloseKey.invoke(root, new Object[] { new Integer(handles[0]) });
  }

  // utility
  private static byte[] toCstr(String str) {
    byte[] result = new byte[str.length() + 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
      result[i] = (byte) str.charAt(i);
    }
    result[str.length()] = 0;
    return result;
  }
}

I am using the winRegTest class to read Value Name and Value data under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\ORACLE\\KEY_OraDb11g_home1 

import java.util.*;
import java.util.Map.Entry;




public class winRegTest {

    /**
     * @param args
     */

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
        try{







                HashMap<String, String> h = WinRegistry.readStringValues(WinRegistry.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,"SOFTWARE\\ORACLE\\KEY_OraDb11g_home1");

                Collection<String> ke;
                for(int i=0; i<h.size();i++){

               ke = h.values(); 
                System.out.println("TKey/Value:" + ke);

                }




                // iterate through the key set and display key and values



        } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }

}
```

```
I get Error:
    java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.String.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.isystem.jReg.WinRegistry.readStringValues(WinRegistry.java:325)
    at com.isystem.jReg.WinRegistry.readStringValues(WinRegistry.java:120)
    at com.isystem.jReg.winRegTest.main(winRegTest.java:35)
```

Questions:

1. My aim is to be able to read all the Name and Data vlaues under each subkey. Am I calling the     method in a correct way?
2. Is there a correct way to read the Key and Value of each Registry Keys?
3. What is the best method to print key value pairs from a Map?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your problem is here :

```
  byte[] name = (byte[]) regEnumValue.invoke(root, new Object[] {
      new Integer
        (handles[0]), new Integer(index), new Integer(maxlen + 1)});
```

`name` probably remains null, which makes the call to `new String(name)` throw `NullPointerException`. You should run your code with a debugger to verify this is the problem.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It fails at this code. I do not know how to make it read the value of  the dword.

Comment: Please let me know if there is any other way to read registry values.

Comment: @user1321074 I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. For me, it turned out the "maxlen" info is not always at the same position, depending (I guess) on the Java version. That is, "regQueryInfoKey.invoke(...)" returns an array of integers, which contain the number of values and max value name length, which are in position 0 and 3 in the given source code; well on my machine it's positions 2 and 4. I've seen examples with 2 and 3. Pretty confusing...

However, there might be a cleaner solution: these indices are in private fields named "VALUES_NUMBER" and "MAX_VALUE_NAME_LENGTH", that you can retrieve this way:

```
Field field=userClass.getDeclaredField("MAX_VALUE_NAME_LENGTH")
field.setAccessible(true);
int maxValueNameLengthINDEX=field.getInt(null);
```

You just do the same for "VALUES_NUMBER".

Not sure if it was the problem encoutered by the OP, but this could help someone else...

Note: tested with Java 1.6.0_18-b07 64 bits. Sorry, I haven't tried other versions so I'm not sure it depends on the Java version, but you can found other examples on the Windows Registry on the net that disagree on the index values...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I spent the whole two days to debug it. I dug deep… (I found this StackOverflow question almost at the end of this process, so I kept it in mind…)

I knew that something is wrong in the method: `private static Map<String, String> readStringValues(…)`

First, I thought that it is just one line: `int count = info[0];` (in my version of the `WinRegistry` class there was a comment that stated that this line was fixed by someone, but while the fix is perfectly valid within the method: `private static List<String> readStringSubKeys(…)`, it is not in this `readStringValues` method).

Only after I analysed this solution: http://alexradzin.blogspot.com/2011/01/access-windows-registry-with-pure-java.html (by AlexR), I learned that there is a second error – at the line: `int maxlen = info[3];` (I was blind, I did not notice it by myself…)

The lines:

```
int count = info[0];
int maxlen = info[3];
```

are perfectly valid in `readStringSubKeys` method, but in the method `readStringValues` they should sound:

```
int count = info[2];
int maxlen = info[4];
```

(Thank you, AlexR! Your code helped us fix another code…)